# EF Ignoring column dynamically to support multiple database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am using EF6 with Code First. I have a Model class something like this

```
public class User
{
public int User_Id { get; set; }
public int User_Name { get; set; }
public int Address { get; set; } //May or may not present in DB
}
```

Here in my application I use multiple DB version where the table column **Address** may or may not exist. 
I know I can use **[NotMapped]** or **Ignore(x=>x.Address)** but this ll not help because I'm not sure about the column exist or not. 
Any suggestion on how to dynamically ignore column much appreciated.

Comment: Then first query the system views to check if the column exists using ADO.net and then call `Ignore` conditionally.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382258/how-to-run-a-query-in-entity-framework-onmodelcreating)