# How to run a query in Entity Framework OnModelCreating

Tags: entity-framework

Any ideas how to run a query in `OnModelCreating`?

I am trying to run a query and then ignore a column in the entity based on that.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     var d = this.Database.SqlQuery<int?>(@"select 1 from sys.columns where Name = N'columnname' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tablename')").SingleOrDefault();

     if(d == null)
     {
         depEntity.Ignore(d => d.colmnname);
     }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe. (See inner exception for details.)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Which part of **The context cannot be used while the model is being created** do you not understand? The error message clearly says: while the model is being created (in the whole `OnModelCreating` method), the context **cannot be used**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have two context classes for both cases. And your query should be invoked inside *Factory* to select class of which instance should be returned:

```
public class CommonContext : DbContext
{
    //common stuff...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //common stuff...
    }
}

public class IgnoreContext : CommonContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepEntity>().Ignore(d => d.colmnname);
    }
}

public ContextFactory()
{
    public CommonContext CreateContext()
    {
         var ctx = new CommonContext();
         var d = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int?>(@"select 1 from sys.columns where Name = N'columnname' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tablename')").SingleOrDefault();
         if(d != null)
             return ctx;             
         return new IgnoreContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite expensive when the application will always need `IgnoreContext`s.